How replace WriteOnlyCollection in DB object - "because the WriteOnlyCollection does not support implicit iteration or direct assignment"
I have an DB object "Part" with a field:
health_indicators: WriteOnlyMapped["HealthIndicators"] = relationship("HealthIndicators",
                                                                      uselist=True, back_populates="part")

So per default health_indicators are never filled but are set to WriteOnlyCollection if read from DB.
Now i want to fill the list with a specific select statement. And provide methods in my PartRepo that return objects with filled HealthIndicators:
def get_part_by_id_filled_latest_hi(self, part_id: str) -> Part | None:

    part = self.get_part_by_id(part_id)
    if part:
        part.health_indicators = self.db_session.scalars(HealthIndicatorsRepo.between_dates_stmt(part_id, None, None)).all() 
        
    return part

The problem is that i am not allowed to replace part.health_indicators:
E  sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Collection "Part.health_indicators" does not support implicit iteration; collection replacement operations can't be used

I understand the meaning and idea behind this error (what if i replace and then safe to db :-P).
Is thee an easy way to provide my "Part" with filled health_indicators? Or can you suggest other way for my use case?
The documentation was not of help here.
What i additionally tried:
part.health_indicators.add_all(self.db_session.scalars(fill_query).all())
What does not yield an error but how to access my items from within an "WriteOnlyCollection" - it seems not an iterable or kind of list.
